# setState() not working in class based component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, mern, web-frontend

```
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: this.articles,
      loading: false
    }
  }

  //always run after the render method
  async componentDidMount(){
    let url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=7d5e22019e7e4b519b0a7776738ac065";
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parseData = await data.json();
    let updateArticle = parseData.articles;
    this.setState({
        articles: updateArticle
    });    // console.log(this.articles)
  }
```

I was expected to replace the articles with updateArticle using setState()
But it is not working but i got the correct value in the updateArticle but cant asssign to articles

Answer (score 0):

`super()` should include props of the component. `this` scope would not work otherwise. check [this related article](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/).

```
// incorrect way
constructor() {
  super();
  // ...
}

// correct way
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: setState() not changing the state even after passing props in constructor and super

Comment: @SyedUrwah did you check the state from `console.log`? the updated state is not accessible in the same scope. you'll have to print it in jsx or use `useEffect` to see it is changed.

Comment: It works after 1 shut down and open the laptop again without changing anything

Comment: glad it worked anyway 